# mysql merge two selects to interleave multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I apologize if the title is abstract.

Is there a way to interleave the null fields in different rows?

ex. original table:

[image]

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(6),
`name` varchar(20),
`content` varchar(20)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`, `content`) VALUES
('1', Null, Null),
(Null, '1', 'aaa'),
(Null, '2', 'bbb'),
('2', Null, Null),
(Null, '3', 'ccc'),
(Null, '4', 'ddd'),
('3', Null, Null),
(Null, '5', 'eee'),
(Null, '6', 'fff');
```

Desired result:

[image]
Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: Will there always be two null values after an id. What is the logic behind such malformed data in your table ?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a good way to do what you are suggesting. Rows have no inherent order; the interleaving you are suggesting assumes an order that just doesn't exist.

<s>Now, if 'test X row Y' always belongs with id = X, that is a different matter...</s>

something like this should work

```
SELECT tB.id, tA.name, tA.content
FROM t AS tA
INNER JOIN t AS tB ON tA.content LIKE CONCAT('test ', tB.id, ' %')
WHERE tA.id IS NULL
;
```

Alternatively, you can get similar results without a join, using string functions to extract the `id` from the `content`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, however the content in the fields are not relevant to any other fields. Sorry about that, I should have modify the content to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the rows in the database are ordered how you want them, so this may be impossible unless there is some way to link the values of the name/content columns to the id column.

If each id will only be associated with two rows, and the names of the tests are simply sequential numbers, it would be possible to map the name to the id and join them. (Join `id` 1 to `name` 1 and 2, `id` 2 to `name` 3  and 4, etc):

```
SELECT a.id, b.name, b.content
FROM test a
JOIN test b
ON a.id = CEILING(b.name / 2)
```

I suspect this isn't the case, so ultimately it is unlikely you can do this select without finding someway to relate the id and the other two columns.